# Plotting a random walk using Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

This is my first time posting here. I would really appreciate some help with a question from my mathematica study guide. My question is:
Suppose that a drunk randomly steps either forward, backward, left, or right one unit many times.  Create a list of coordinates {{x,y}..} representing his path and then display that path as a set of line segments for each step.  [Hint: use NestList to create a list of coordinates, Partition to form a list of segments, map Line onto the segment list, and Show[Graphics[list]] to display the path.]
I have managed to successfully create the function:

```
Clear[x, n]

Randomwalk[n_] :=
  NestList[(# + (-1)^Table[Random[Integer, {0, 1}], {2}]) &, Table[0, {2}], n];

Randomwalk[50]
```

I, however, need help with the second part, where I need to graph it. MY attempt at the second part is as follows:

```
Show[Graphics[Line[Randomwalk[50]]]]
```

and although it gives me a graph, it does not seem to be correct. I would really appreciate some help with this.

Comment: I'll recommend posting Mathematica questions to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following function

```
RandomWalk[n_]:=Accumulate[{{1,0},{-1,0},{0,1},{0,-1}}[[RandomInteger[{1,4},n]]]]
```

where `n` is the number of steps to take. Plotting works as you wrote

```
Graphics[Line[RandomWalk[200]]]
```

However, plotting with colour shows how the walk progressed, as in

```
With[{n=100},
   Graphics[MapIndexed[{Hue[#2[[1]]/(n + 10)], Line[#]} &, 
               Partition[RandomWalk[n], 2, 1]]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using [[RandomInteger[{1,4},n]]] to pick out the directions, you could use RandomChoice which is designed expressly for this type of operation:

```
RandomWalk[n_] := Accumulate[RandomChoice[{{1, 0}, {-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, -1}}, n]]
```

This gives about the same (maybe slightly faster) speed as the approach using Part and RandomInteger. But if you are working with large walks (n > 10^6, say), then you might want to squeeze some speed out by forcing the list of directions to be a packed array:

```
NSEWPacked = Developer`ToPackedArray[{{1, 0}, {-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, -1}}]
```

Then use the packed array:

```
RandomWalkPacked[n_] := Accumulate[RandomChoice[NSEWPacked, n]]
```

You should see about an order of magnitude speedup with this:

```
Timing[RandomWalkPacked[10^7];]
```

For details on packed arrays, see Developer/ref/ToPackedArray or chapter 12 on optimizing Mathematica programs in [*Programming with Mathematica: An Introduction*](http://www.cambridge.org/wellin).

Comment: Thanks for the tips, Paul, and also the book link. I have several of your books, and was unaware of your latest.

Comment: Paul, I invite you to join us on the dedicated *Mathematica* StackExchange site: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com  Nearly all of the experienced MMA users on the network have moved over.  I hope to see you there!